# Can't start apache2 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I'm a newbie in Linux and I can't start apache2. this is the error I' getting when I put in terminal `service apache2 status`:

```
service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since lun 2016-11-07 12:33:44 ECT; 24s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16093 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAIL

nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]:  *
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]: Output of config test was:
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of 
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]: Action 'configtest' failed.
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign apache2[16093]: The Apache error log may have more in
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, 
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed stat
nov 07 12:33:44 EbalDesign systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: There's a syntax error in line 140 of one of Apache's configuration files but we can't tell which one because the log output seems to be truncated. Could you please run the `status` command again and redirect it into a file so it's not truncated according to the terminal width?